# How to install and uninstall a script sourced in all interactive shells via yum on Centos?

Tags: shell, centos, yum, rpm

I would like to package, install and uninstall a rpm which can add a contextual warning message at all interactive shells startup for all users (actually, at least both bash ssh session and bash gnome terminal). Basically, the code would display the warning message if a file is missing.

Well, the candidates are `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/myscript.sh`, `/etc/skel/.bash_profile`, `/etc/skel/.bashrc`.

The easiest way would be to install something in `/etc/profile.d` but it doesn't really address my need (ssh bash session).
I think the right place is `/etc/skel/.bashrc + exisiting .bashrc` but I don't feel safe with appending/removing my code to/from these files... My understanding is that `yum` and `rpm` puts and remove files; they are not designed to safely modify text files.
I would like something like `/etc/bashrc.d/` ...

Where should I **safely install** the warning message so it can be available in all  interactive shells and **safely uninstalled**? By safely, I mean without deleting anything unwanted.

Comment: What about `/etc/motd`?

Comment: The text in `/etc/motd` can't be executed: this is not a script. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/etc/bashrc` is marked as `%config(noreplace)` file in the `setup` rpm. This means that if you update it, `yum` will *not* replace it.  When upgrading a package, if there is an updated `/etc/bashrc`, `yum` will create `/etc/bashrc.rpmnew`.  So you *can* modify it safely if you wish.

But it appears that won't be necessary.  Take a look at `/etc/bashrc` on your centos/rhel/fedora/etc system, and you will find:

```
if ! shopt -q login_shell ; then # We're not a login shell
[...]
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r "$i" ]; then
            if [ "$PS1" ]; then
                . "$i"
            else
                . "$i" >/dev/null
            fi
        fi
    done
[...]
```

That code ensures that the files in `/etc/profile.d` are run both for login shells (in which case they are run from `/etc/profile` instead) and for non-login shells (in which case this loop takes care of running them).

In other words, you *already* have an `/etc/bashrc.d`, and it's called `/etc/profile.d`.

Comment: Note, that `/etc/bashrc*` will only work for bash shells. `/etc/profile` will work for many shells, but not some like `csh`.

Comment: Thanks, I put a file in `/etc/profile.d`. However, as @Patrick points out, the script must work with all other shells... And I'm still a bit worried: my script displays a message and I think it can disturbs some apps while loaded in `/etc/profile`. Indeed `/etc/profile.d`is broader than an hypothetical `/etc/bashrc.d/`.

Comment: If you restrict your script to only run in interactive shells (`PS1` is set) it shouldn't disturb anything.  You're correct that this only covers bash/bourne shells.  There's not really a way to get a script to run for "all interactive shell invocations, regardless of which shell".  You could use something like `pam_exec` to run a script for all logins,  but this wouldn't trigger e.g. when opening a new gnome-terminal.

Comment: You are right, I will check for PS1 in my script!